# Neon IFFT compared to Python's NumPy IFFT - why the results are different?

Tags: python, c, signal-processing, fft, neon

As part of our development we develop algorithms in `Python 3.8` (with `NumPy 1.19`). We then implement it in `C` using `neon` NE10 library.
In one stage we compute inverse Fourier transform using built-in IFFT functions.
When we compare between `neon (NE10)` (last version) IFFT and Python's `NumPy 1.19` IFFT we get different result (they not differ by much, but the different is far bigger than the numerical precision, see outputs below).

The Python code:

```
import numpy as np

NFFT = 4096
FREQUENCY_BINS = 2049
NUMBER_OF_OUTPUTS = 4

in02_IFFT = np.zeros((NFFT, NUMBER_OF_OUTPUTS))*(0+0j)

# Generating the input
half = np.zeros((FREQUENCY_BINS,NUMBER_OF_OUTPUTS))*(0+0j)
  for n in range(FREQUENCY_BINS):
    half[n,:] = n % 8 + (n % 4)*1j
    
# Taking symmetric conjugate for the other half so the output will be real
mirror = np.flip( np.conj(half[1:-1,:]), axis=0 ) # mirror-reflect frequencies
in02_IFFT = np.vstack((half, mirror)) 

 out02_IFFT = np.ones((NFFT, NUMBER_OF_OUTPUTS))*(1+0j)
 for i in range(NUMBER_OF_OUTPUTS):
    out02_IFFT[:,i] = np.fft.ifft(in02_IFFT[:,i])

 print(in02_IFFT[0:12,0])
 print(out02_IFFT[0:12,0])
```

Here is the output for the first 12 entries:

```
Input[0:12,0] =
[0.+0.j 1.+1.j 2.+2.j 3.+3.j 4.+0.j 5.+1.j 6.+2.j 7.+3.j 0.+0.j 1.+1.j
 2.+2.j 3.+3.j]

Output[0:12,0] =
[ 3.5       +0.j -0.95834839+0.j  0.        +0.j -0.32173021+0.j
  0.        +0.j -0.19440795+0.j  0.        +0.j -0.13984233+0.j
  0.        +0.j -0.10952898+0.j  0.        +0.j -0.09023946+0.j]
```

The neon function is `ne10_fft_c2r_1d_float32_neon` and the call is:

```
ne10_fft_c2r_1d_float32_neon( data_time_final[output_channel_number], BUFFER_BF_OUTPUT[output_channel_number], cfg_fft_r2c );
```

See documentation: https://github.com/projectNe10/Ne10/blob/master/inc/NE10_dsp.h

And the output:

```
3.500000000000000000
-0.958348393440246582
0.000000009662471712
-0.321730166673660278,
0.000000001629814506
-0.194407939910888672
-0.000000014028046280
-0.139842316508293152
0.000000007217749953
-0.109529010951519012
0.000000007741618901
-0.090239435434341431
```

However, for a "real life" data the outputs differ significantly:

```
After IFFT Python: [-5.75256348e-08+0.j -1.14624023e-07+0.j -2.39105225e-07+0.j  -3.28216553e-07+0.j]
After IFFT C: [-5.58793545e-08 -1.11758709e-07 -2.42143869e-07 -3.29688191e-07]
```

Can you explain why the results are different and not the same up to a relative error of `1e-6`

Answer (score 2):

Generally, numerical round off error increases with the FFT transform size. Also, different FFT implementations may have different round off error. E.g. some use recurrence formulas that reduce memory cost, but create larger round off errors.

This page on FFTW is an accuracy comparison of various FFT implementations:
http://www.fftw.org/accuracy/Pentium4-3.60GHz-icc/
For a 4096-size FFT on 32-bit float data, some implementations do get worse than 1e-6 relative RMS error. See also [their commentary](http://www.fftw.org/accuracy/comments.html) on FFT accuracy.

Comment: Do you know what FFT algorithm, from the 1st link, the NE10 library uses?

Comment: Huh, FFT implementation is probably not the reason for the error you observe. Looking over NE10, `ne10_fft_c2r_1d_float32_neon` is a mixed radix-2/4 Cooley-Tukey FFT. The twiddles appear to be accurately precomputed, directly calling cos() and sin(), not by a recurrence like FFTW's page warns about. I'd expect NE10's accuracy to be good.